# Is a subset that contains no positive measurable subsets contained in a null measurable set?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal B, \mu)$ be a "good" measure space, e.g. $\mu$ is a positive Radon measure on a locally compact topological space $X$ with Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B$. Let $A\subset X$ such that every measurable subset of $A$ has zero measure. Is it true that there is a zero measure set $B$ such that $A\subset B$?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are asking whether every set with inner measure $0$ has measure $0$ with respect to the completion measure. The Lebesgue measure, for example, does not have this property, since the usual Vitali set is non-measurable, but has inner measure $0$.

I claim that a ($\sigma$-finite) measure space has your property if and only if every set
is measurable with respect to its completion measure.

For the forward direction, suppose that $A$ is any subset
of the space $X$. Let $a$ be the inner measure of $A$, the
supremum of $\mu(A_0)$ among all measurable $A_0\subset A$ (and we may assume wlog this is finite).
By taking a union, it follows that the inner measure is
realized, so that there is some measurable $A_0\subset A$
with $\mu(A_0)=a$. It follows that $A-A_0$ has inner
measure $0$. By the hypothesis, it follows that
$A-A_0\subset B$ for some measurable set $B$ with
$\mu(B)=0$, and so $A-A_0$ has measure $0$ with respect to
the completion. Consequently, $A$ differs from the
measurable set $A_0$ on a completion-measure zero set
$A-A_0$, and hence is measurable with respect to the
completion measure.

Conversely, suppose that every set is measurable with
respect to the completion of $\mu$. Suppose that $A$ has
inner measure $0$. By assumption, there is some measurable
set $A_0$ such that the symmetric difference $A\triangle
A_0\subset A_1$ for some measurable $A_1$ with
$\mu(A_1)=0$. It follows that $A_0-A_1$ is a measurable
subset of $A$, and hence measure $0$, and so $A\subset
B=A_0\cup A_1=(A_0-A_1)\cup A_1$ shows that $A$ is contained
in a measure $0$ set $B$, as desired.

In particular, a complete measure has the property if and
only if it measures every set.

Comment: On the other hand, if one assumes determinacy (that contradicts choice), then the result is true (at least in any decent space). For example, for the reals we in fact have that if the only *Borel* subsets of $A$ are measure zero, then $A$ is contained in a Borel set of measure zero. Note that Joel's argument does not use choice after the first paragraph.